# Is this possible to train an exist custom classifier once it has been created

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I had a custom classifier created some while ago, and now I wish to train this specific classifier with more positive and negative images and with the classifier ID available.

Is it possible to train this classifier? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to updated existing classifiers.  You can learn more about this process in the docs here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/customizing.shtml#retrain

> You can update an existing classifier by adding new classes, or by adding new images to existing classes. To update the existing classifier, use several compressed (.zip) files, including files containing positive or negative images (.jpg, or .png). You must supply at least one compressed file, with additional positive or negative examples.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is possible but only with the **standard plan** (not with the **free plan**).

With the **free plan** you will have to `delete` then `create` again your classifier.

> You can update an existing classifier by adding new classes, or by
>   adding new images to existing classes.

**Update CURL :**

```
curl -X POST -F "golden_positive_examples=@golden-retriever.zip" -F "negative_examples=@more-cats.zip" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers/{classifier_id}?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

**API reference Link :**

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/#update_a_classifier

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible. As reported in the [Visual Recognition Docs](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/customizing.shtml):

> When you create a new classifier, it is trained with only the images
>   you provide in that API call. Therefore, you cannot update an existing
>   classifier; you can only create new classifiers or delete existing
>   classifiers.

Please also note that custom classifiers that are created while the Visual Recognition service is in beta will need to be re-created when the service reaches General Availability.